# File select (Image) for coldfusion form...save filename in form for database

Tags: html, forms, coldfusion

I am kinda stuck on what I need to do here. I have a form, I want the end user to be able to select an image on the server in a specific folder (gfx/images/) to be updated to the database when the form is submitted. I have everything working properly however I can't figure this out and using  I dont think is what I need. I am completely open to suggestions.

```
<form name="UpdateFishForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Query/UpdateFish.cfc?PK=#PK#">
  <h1>Update #FishName#</h1>
    <label>Fish Name:</label><input name="FishName" value="#FishName#" />
    <input name="PK" value="#PK#" hidden="true">
    <br />
    <label>Fish Genus:</label>
    <select name="FishGenus">
        <option value="#FishGenus#" selected="selected">
            <cfif #FishGenus# eq 1>
                Hap
            <cfelseif #FishGenus# eq 2>
                Peacock
            <cfelseif #FishGenus# eq 3>
                Mbuna
            <cfelseif #FishGenus# eq 4>
                Tang
            <cfelseif #FishGenus# eq 5>
                Victorian
            <cfelseif #FishGenus# eq 6>
                Cat Fish / Pleco
            <cfelse>

                Other
            </cfif>
        </option>
        <option value="1">Hap</option>
        <option value="2">Peacock</option>
        <option value="3">Mbuna</option>
        <option value="4">Tang</option>
        <option value="5">Victorian</option>
        <option value="6">Cat Fish / Pleco</option>
        <option value="7">Other</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Fish Image:</label><input  name="FishImage" type="file" value="#FishImage#" />
    <br />
    <label>Fish Type:</label>
    <select name="FishType" Placeholder="FishType">
        <option value="#FishType#" selected="selected">#FishType#</option>
        <option value="Wild Caught">Wild Caught</option>
        <option value="F1">F1</option>
        <option value="F2">F2</option>
        <option value="Tank Raised">Tank Raised</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Fish Directory:</label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Fish Size</th>
            <th>Fish Sex</th>
            <th>Fish Quantity</th>
            <th>Fish Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##1:</label><input name="Fish1size" value="#Fish1Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish1Sex">
                <option value="#Fish1Sex#">#Fish1Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish1Qty" value="#Fish1Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish1Price" value="#Fish1Price#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##2:</label><input name="Fish2size" value="#Fish2Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish2Sex">
                <option value="#Fish2Sex#">#Fish2Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish2Qty" value="#Fish2Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish2Price" value="#Fish2Price#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##3:</label><input name="Fish3size" value="#Fish3Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish3Sex">
                <option value="#Fish3Sex#">#Fish3Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish3Qty" value="#Fish3Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish3Price" value="#Fish3Price#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##4:</label><input name="Fish4size" value="#Fish4Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish4Sex">
                <option value="#Fish4Sex#">#Fish4Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish4Qty" value="#Fish4Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish4Price" value="#Fish4Price#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##5:</label><input name="Fish5size" value="#Fish5Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish5Sex">
                <option value="#Fish5Sex#">#Fish5Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish5Qty" value="#Fish5Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish5Price" value="#Fish5Price#"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Fish ##6:</label><input name="Fish6size" value="#Fish6Size#"/></td>
            <td><select name="Fish6Sex">
                <option value="#Fish6Sex#">#Fish6Sex#</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Unsexed">Unsexed</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="Fish6Qty" value="#Fish6Qty#"></td>
            <td><input name="Fish6Price" value="#Fish6Price#"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
   <p>Discription</p>
   <textarea cols="70" rows="6" name="FishDescription" style="margin-left:5px; margin-top:-10px">#FishDescription#</textarea>
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit"  />
   </form>
   </cfoutput>
```

Comment: The second sentence of your prose is that you want the user to select a file on the server.  The first line of your code is what you would use for users to pick files from their local machine.  Try taking this one step at a time.

Comment: Correct, that is how I was orginally thinking of doing it.

Comment: Would it be easier to let the user attach an image, upload it and save it?

Comment: I always consider satisfying a business requirement to be more important than ease of programming.